# Как настроить дизайн стандартного HTML5-аудиопроигрывателя.

Tags: аудио, html5

Как можно изменить дизайн стандартного HTML5-аудиопроигрывателя? (речь идёт о настройке тега <audio>). Надо поменять дизайн дорожки, кнопки play/pause, и т.д.
Такая возможность вообще есть? Поменять дизайн нужно кардинальным способом, т.е. не просто поменять фон, а настроить проигрыватель под свои нужды.
здесь: http://htmlbook.ru/html/audio описаны кое какие настройки, но этого мало.

Answer (score 2):

Никак. Единственный вариант дублировать функционал в скрипте. У [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/) неплохо получилось.

Answer (score 0):

Способ есть. Используйте бесплатный конструктор аудио/видео плееров uppod.ru